# a proof for $\sum \limits_{n\le x} c_n f(n)=S(x)f(x)-\int \limits_{n_0}^x S(t)f'(t)dt$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to go through the book "An Introduction to Sieve Methods and their Application" by Cojocaru & Murty. On page 4 one can find the Theorem 1.3.1, that $\sum \limits_{n\le x} c_n f(n)=S(x)f(x)-\int \limits_{n_0}^x S(t)f'(t)dt$ is true with $S(x)=\sum \limits_{n\le x} c_n$ and $c_j =0$ for all $j<n_0$.

This formula looks like a discrete version of the chain rule and could be true, but if I take an example, it doesn't work. We can set $c_0=0$ and $c_n=1$ for all $n>0$ and $f(n)=n$. We know, that $\sum \limits_{n\le x} n=\frac{1}{2} x(x+1)$, but $S(x)f(x)-\int \limits_{n_0}^x S(t)f'(t)dt=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+1)$.

In the given proof of that theorem in the book I don't understand the step to the last line, thats why I took the example.

The proof in the book is very short, so I can copy it.
$\begin{align}
\sum \limits_{n\le x} c_n f(n)&=\sum \limits_{n\le x} S(n)f(n) -\sum \limits_{n\le x-1} S(n)f(n+1)\\
&=S(x)f(x)-\sum \limits_{n\le x-1} S(n)\int \limits_n^{n+1}f'(t)dt\\
&=S(x)f(x)-\int \limits_{n_0}^x S(t)f'(t)dt
\end{align}$

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong.  With your example $c_n = 1$ for $n \geq 1$ and $f(n) = n$, you have $S(t) = \lfloor t \rfloor$, so the formula reads (assuming $x$ is an integer)
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \leq x} n \cdot 1 &= S(x) f(x) - \int_1^x S(t) f'(t) \,dt = x \cdot x - \int_1^x \lfloor t \rfloor \cdot 1 \,dt \\
&= x^2 - (1+2+\dots+(x-1)) = x^2 - \frac{(x-1)x}{2} = \frac{x(x+1)}{2}
\end{align*}
The formula is correct, it's just not useful in this particular example, because the only way to evaluate the integral term is to already know the answer to the sum you're trying to evaluate.

As a remark, you should think of this formula more like a discrete version of integration by parts rather than a discrete version of the chain rule.

Comment: Thank you. I meant the discrete version of integration by parts, I only took the wrong translation. My failure was the misunderstanding of $S(t)$ as a continuous function?

Comment: Yeah you have to interpret $S(t)$ as $\sum_{n \leq \lfloor t \rfloor} c_n$, so it's defined for all positive $t$ but only changes values at integer $t$